# Prettier config for javascript code indenting

Tags: javascript, typescript, prettier

I am using Prettier in Visual Studio Code for formatting.

Normally, it works great in my JS/TS files.  But it insists on wrapping code like this onto single lines:

```
trigger('myInsertRemoveTrigger', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate('5s', style({ opacity: 1 })),
  ]),
  transition(':leave', [
    animate('5s', style({ opacity: 0 }))
  ])
]),
```

becomes like

```
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('.5s', style({ opacity: 1 }))]),
      transition(':leave', [animate('.5s', style({ opacity: 0 }))])
    ])
```

Which I find harder to read.  I've looked at the [available options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) and don't see anything related to this.  Can I configure this somehow?

Currently, my `.prettierrc` is

```
{
  "printWidth": 120,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

prettier is opiniated, and thus you can not configure the way it does reformat your code : you just have to accept the indentation made by prettier :)

Comment: I was afraid of that

Comment: Be not afraid of that. **Opinionated and automated code formatting** is a technique that saves a ton of time. https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques advises that the *key here is not to spend hours discussing which rules to enforce, but instead pick a tool that is opinionated, **minimally configurable** and automated.* (emphasis added).

Answer (score 1):

Just add a comment after the first element of the array.

```
var a = [
  1, //
  2,
  3,
];
```

Comment: I think your hack was exactly what was asked for - not the other stuff though.

Comment: @sylvanaar hope this helps. I thought i could also share a different perspective.  Hacks don't go well with all users :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - so I made some edits and upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only thing you can do is reduce `printWidth`.
But that will obviously affect the rest of your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing, it sounds like you are talking exactly about 'print width'. Try decreasing the 'print width' to 80 or less. Maybe 50 depending on what your preference is.

```
{
  "printWidth": 80,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "useTabs": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true
 }
```